# jQuery Click issue for slideUp and SlideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in one of my drupal page i have 3 drop menu . when i click on each of theme, it has to open a dropDown menu, but wont work. you can see js and css of that page.

this is my web page : http://pajoohyar.ir/start_standalone

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Base Styles */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    direction: rtl;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: tahoma, "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu {
    width: 750px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    direction: rtl;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    background: #565656;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #565656), color-stop(100%, #323232));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: #97be10;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#97be10 0%, #79980d 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #97be10), color-stop(100%, #79980d));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#97be10 0%, #79980d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#97be10 0%, #79980d 100%);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    border: 1px solid #79980d;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
    border: 1px solid #97be10;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_plus.png) 2% center no-repeat;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_minus.png) 2% center no-repeat;
}


/* Sub menu */

#cssmenu ul ul {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
    padding: 3px 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #595959;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #79980d;
}

#borderimg1 {
    border: 10px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
    /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
    /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    //border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}

.divstyyle {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of your HTML structure. You have sometimes two links for open the dropdown instead of just one and it cause trouble with the `next()` selector

The second problem was the inline style on `ul` element in your HTML code, especially `height: 1px;` part.

[See this working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxgar99s/3/)